# Communities Registration Error

Tags: community, customer-community

I created a customer community, when a new customer is register at that time it showing an error May i know what i have to do.

[image: site image] Below is my image
  the error which i am getting is Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted.

Answer (score 1):

Check your email (or ask the sys admin to do so if you are not the admin). It will have the actual error message in it.